# How can I duplicate the stream for my FB Page (including updates and comments) on my website?

Tags: facebook, stream, widget, comments

In short, I want to duplicate as closely as possible the functionality of a Facebook Page stream on my own website.

The Like Box widget only shows updates by the page, but I would also like to show the comments for the updates (preferably in the same way as on the Facebook Page), and have what other users have posted on the Page's wall be included in the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Neosmart's fb.wall jQuery plugin and customizing it turned out to be pretty easy. NeoSmart has since come out with a successor for the fb.wall plugin, called [NeoSmart Stream](http://www.neosmart-stream.com/).

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Facebook API: allow my own website to access my profile, semi-permanently](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7939617/facebook-api-allow-my-own-website-to-access-my-profile-semi-permanently/7940044#7940044)

The only difference here is that you should be getting your page access token instead of a user access token - rchanges from my answer above are:

3a - make sure you get the manage_pages permission

4a - make a call to /me/accounts to get the page access token

Comment: This takes care of the authentication so that my website has access to the Page content through JavaScript, but it doesn't really help with actually duplicating the stream functionality on my website. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: You could pull (cache?) the posts server or client side and format them in your own style - make a Graph API call (using the page access token) to /{page id}/feed and you'll get back the recent posts on the page's wall, including their comments and likes - use the Graph API explorer to test out what the call and return types are (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) - there should be enough information to recreate wall yourself, including user photos

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin that does much of this (http://www.neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall). By looking at the code of that plugin, and considering it's still missing like functionality and commenting, this does not seem like a trivial task.